# why add fillers in a c++ struct?

Tags: c++, c

What are the effect of fillers in a c++ struct? I often see them in some c++ api. For example:

```
struct example
{
    unsigned short a;
    unsigned short b;
    char c[3];
    char filler1;
    unsigned short e;
    char filler2;
    unsigned int g;
};
```

This struct is meant to transport through network

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Since this is a POD you can define your memory layout. Did anyone optimize the code for a specific CPU?

Comment: Well, in fact, the *real* purpose of declaring fillers, is to be able to access the data in the "gaps", i.e. having a named member to do so and not an `additional unnamed data member` as stated in Anon's answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
struct example
{
    unsigned short a; //2 bytes
    unsigned short b;//2 bytes
            //4 bytes consumed
    char c[3];//3 bytes
    char filler1;//1 bytes
            //4 bytes consumed
    unsigned short e;//2 bytes
    char filler2;//1 bytes
            //3 bytes consumed ,should be filler[2]
    unsigned int g;//4 bytes
};
```

Comment: I learned about this when I tried to implement the Bitmap header and read from a file directly into that.
You have `struct bmp_header { char magic[2]; int something; [...] }`. It took me 3 days to figure out where were going the 2 octets after "BM" from my file, as the `int something` started on byte 4 and not on byte 2 as expected !

Comment: You should have used #pragma pack(1) ...and issue fired away..  ;-)

Comment: I tried __attribute__((packed)), problem is : memory was not aligned after that -> crashhhhhh

Comment: So i opted for the lazy way out : read 2 bytes, check if it's BM and read the rest inside the struct :)

Comment: Oh and by the way, @Anon, beware of `#pragma`, as it is implementation-dependant in the compiler. According to standards, compilers can do whatever they want when stumbling on a `#pragma` in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Because sometimes you don't actually control the format of the data you're using.

The format may be specified by something beyond your control. For example, it may be created in a system with different alignment requirements to yours.

Alternatively, the data may have real data in those filler areas that your code doesn't care about.

Answer (score 3):

Those fillers are usually inserted to explicitly make sure some of the members of a structure are naturally aligned i.e. their offset inside a structure is a multiple of its size.

In the example below assuming char is 1 bytes, short is 2 and int is 4.

```
struct example
{
    unsigned short a;
    unsigned short b;
    char c[3];
    char filler1;
    unsigned short e; // starts at offset 8
    char filler2[2];
    unsigned int g; // starts at offset 12
};
```

If you don't specify any fillers, a compiler will usually add the necessary padding bytes to ensure a proper alignment of the structure members.

Btw, these fields can also be used for reserved fields that might appear in the future.

**updated:**

Since it has been mentioned that a structure is a network packet, the fillers are required to get a structure that is compatible with the one being passed from another host.

However, inserting filler bytes in this case might not be enough (especially, if portability is required). If these structures are to be sent via a network as is (i.e. without manually packing into a separate buffer for sending), you have to inform a compiler that the structure should be packed.

In microsoft compiler this can be achieved using `#pragma pack`:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct T {
   char t; 
   int i;
   short j;
   double k;
};
```

In gcc you can use `__attribute__((packed))`

```
struct foo {
        char c;
        int x;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

However, many people prefer to manually pack/unpack structures int a raw-byte array, because accessing misaligned data on some systems might not be [properly] supported.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what code you're working with they may be attempting to align the structure on word boundries (32 bit in your case), this is a speed optimization, however, doing things like this has been rendered obsolete by decent optimizing compilers, however if the compiler was instructed not to optimize this piece of code, or the compiler is very low-end e.g. for an embedded system, it may be better to handle this yourself.  It basically boils downto how much you trust the compiler.

The other reason is for writing binary files, where reserved bytes have been left in the file format specification.

Comment: "rendered obsolete by decent optimizing compilers" - not so... precompiled objects that may have been compiled with different compilers or compiler optimisation priorities can lay out objects differently, _without any particular speed/space compromise being inherently flawed and obsolete_.  This approach to padding effectively puts common-sense constraints on the compiler(s) to force more consistent alignment regardless of likely variations in optimisation settings.  "the other reason" is another reason, but there are yet-others such as network packets and shared memory from external systems.

Comment: Ok, so I was over simplifying, and obsolete was a bit harsh, but in essence what I meant is:

Most of the time it's not an issue these days, but if you are doing anything that needs special care (like where I said you might tell your compiler not to optimize), or you need to match a spec, that's where you might do it.

Comment: Hi Tony. yes it is a network packet. how does it make thing faster?